# $\int_3^5\log(2^{1/2}+x^{1/2})\,dx$

Tags: logarithms

I need an approximate value for
$$\int_3^5\log(2^{1/2}+x^{1/2})\,dx$$
Using the trapezium rule I worked out
$$\int_3^5\log(2+x)\,dx=1.55$$
Do I just halve the area now?

Answer (score 0):

No: you could halve the area if it were $\int_3^5 \log\sqrt{2+x}\,dx$, but $2^{1/2}+x^{1/2}\neq (2+x)^{1/2}$.